# Not able to add timestamp to minicom readings

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, timestamp, minicom

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. I am using minicom to capture bluetooth data. The data is displayed fine, but when I try to add timestamp using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by  <kbd>N</kbd>.

I don't see any time stamp on the console. I checked the minicom Ubuntu documetation for 14.04. It says that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by  <kbd>N</kbd> is to be used for timestamp. I also checked the settings using `minicom -s`, but I couldn't find any thing to activate the timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

You can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>N</kbd> to enable timestamp. Do this again to cycle between different modes of timestamp

Quoting the [Ubuntu man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/minicom.1.html)

> N     Toggle between three states, whether each line is  prefixed  with  current  date and time, a timestamp is added every second, or no timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then a window will be displayed there type <kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: in questions and answers you can use the [markdown](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help) and limited [inline html](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#html) to improve the format. In this case you could wrap the keys to be pressed in <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to make them look like keys. It is preferred to include references or additional reading links when appropriate or possible.